# What is the equation of a tangent to a circle at a point?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, circles

Suppose I have the following circle
$$
(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 = r^2
$$
where the center $(x_0, y_0)$ and the radius $r$ are known. Is there a general formula for the equation of a tangent at a point $(a, b)$ on the circle, with $a, b$ known?

## Idea

Since the point $(a, b)$ is on the circle, we must have
$$
(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2
$$
and since the tangent will pass through $(a, b)$ we must have
$$
\frac{y - b}{x - a} = m
$$

> *How do you incorporate the fact that the radius is perpendicular to the tangent?*

Following the comments, I think then one notices that the radius is perpendicular to the tangent. The line through the center $(x_0, y_0)$ and the point $(a, b)$ has slope

$$
m' = \frac{b - y_0}{a - x_0}
$$

Since this line must be perpendicular to the tangent,  we must have that

$$
m'm = -1
$$

Therefore we can already find the slope as
$$
m = -\frac{1}{m'} = - \frac{a - x_0}{b - y_0}
$$

Now we just need to find the intercept. Plugging $(a, b)$ into $y = mx + q$ with the $m$ that we've just found we find
$$
b = ma + q
$$
and so
$$
b + a\left(\frac{a - x_0}{b - y_0}\right)
$$
The final equation is
$$
y = -\frac{a - x_0}{b - y_0} x + b + a\left(\frac{a - x_0}{b - y_0}\right)
$$

[image]

Comment: Yes. But try working it out for yourself by computing the slope of the radius to the point on the circle you are interested in. You want the line through that point perpendicular to the radius. Do you know the property of slopes which applies when two lines are perpendicular to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y - b = -\frac{a-x_0}{b-y_0}(x-a)$$

(Tangents are perpendicular to radii, and then just use the standard equation of a line of known gradient through a point)

Comment: I have a minus sign at the start of the fraction on the RHS, so our answers are identical.

Comment: Ah ok. Not showing up on my browser for some reason. As you were.

Answer (score 1):

(A bit different take on this from the other answers...)

Yes.

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+r^2=(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2$$

This formula comes from Pythagoras' theorem applied to the right-angled triangle with corners $(x,y)$, $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(a,b)$. It is a formula for a line because $x^2$ and $y^2$ will cancel when you expand LHS and RHS.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

The tangent should pass through the circumference point (a, b) and since its perpendicular to the radius, it should have a slope negative reciprocal of the slope of the radius vector

Comment: How do you incorporate the fact that the radius is perpendicular to the tangent?

Comment: if two lines are perpendicular then the product of their slope is -1 , (minus one)

Answer (score 0):

Label $(x_0, y_0)$ as $O$, $(a,b)$ as $T$ and let $P$ be an arbitrary point on the tangent line at $(x,y)$.

Then the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) $OT.TP = 0$ because the vectors need to be perpendicular, which calculates out as

$(a-x_0)(x-a) + (b-y_0)(y-b) = 0$
$(y-b) = \dfrac{(a-x_0)}{(b-y_0)}(a-x)$